# Android emulator keyboard crashes when displaying number keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, emulation

Whenever I run my android project in emulator and I click on an editText field, the alphabetic keyboard works fine, but when I click on the number keyboard, it crashes with the message:  Android Keyboard (AOSP) has stopped.

I thought maybe it was some bad code in my project, so I created a fresh project with no code and a simple editText, same problem.

I tried uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling, same problem.

I tried running Android Studio on another computer with a different operating system.  Same problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure numeric input for your EditText by using the following in the xml:

```
 `<EditText android:inputType="number `
```